Coldfusion Form with embedded cfloop gives comma delimited values
The following form is an overly simplified version for a bigger project:
If I select a line to delete, all I want to do is display the value I selected and not 1,2,3,4. So, if I select the DELETE for row A2 B2 ROW: 2, I should only get 2!  The cfloop is adding all the values to the test variable.

There has to be an easy solution to this!
<h1>HELLO!</h1>
<cfif StructKeyExists(FORM,"delete")>
    <h1><cfoutput>#FORM.thisRow#</cfoutput></h1><cfabort>
<cfelse>
    <cfset count  = 4>
</cfif>

<cfoutput>
    <cfform action="test4.cfm" id="updateForm2" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="delete">
        <table>
            <cfloop index="row" from="1" to="#count#">
                <cfset test=#row#>
                <tr>
                    <td>A#row#</td>
                    <td>B#row#</td>
                    <td>ROW: #row#</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="DELETE"></td>
                </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="thisRow" value="#test#">
            </cfloop>
        </table>
    </cfform>
</cfoutput>
<h1><cfoutput>#test#</cfoutput></h1>

Here is what I get instead:


Use a  after the  tags, like this, A#row#

First, you are naming all the fields in the loop the same.  You need to name them uniquely to submit them with unique values.
It doesn't matter what button you push they all get submitted.
There are lots of ways to solve this problem.

You could have each button be its own form.
You could change the submit buttons to be just a button and use javascript to submit a value.

Also, there is no need to use CFFORM for this form or any form actually.  There are much better solutions out there.  Just use a regular HTML FORM.

Actually, you need to make some distinction to figure out that which DELETE button has been clicked. Although, there are some other ways to do it. However, I have used your code with minimal changes to get your required result.

    <cfparam name="count" default=4>
<h1>HELLO!</h1>
<cfif StructKeyExists(FORM,"delete")>
    <cfloop from=1 to="#count#" index=i>
        <cfif isDefined("form.submit#i#")>
             <h1><cfoutput>#Evaluate("FORM.thisRow#i#")#</cfoutput></h1><cfabort> 
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    
</cfif>

<cfoutput>
    <cfform action="test4.cfm" id="updateForm2" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="delete">
        <table>
            <cfloop index="row" from="1" to="#count#">
                <cfset test=#row#>
                <tr>
                    <td>A#row#</td>
                    <td>B#row#</td>
                    <td>ROW: #row#</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit#row#" value="DELETE"></td>
                </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="thisRow#row#" value="#test#">
            </cfloop>
        </table>
    </cfform>
</cfoutput>
<h1><cfoutput>#test#</cfoutput></h1>

